# GETUID code capped out at 1000 how to overcome this

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following simple code. I didn't think we would reach 1K so quick in issues but the code stopped working at 1000. How do I keep from running into this problem in the future?

```
Public Function GetUID() As String

    GetUID = "SCR" & Right("000" + CStr((CInt(Right(DMax("[SCR ID]", "Master Shared Compliance Review"), 3)) + 1)), 5)

End Function
```

Comment: Y2K strikes again

Comment: Use format to format your display values. Besides use long as vba integer is 2byte 32k max

Comment: If none of the answers work, a simple fix (given that you are already beyond `"SCR00099"` would be to change the `3` in your current code to be `5`.  (And change `CInt` to `CLng` if you want to get past 32767 at some stage.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opted for this solution if anyone needs to accomplish the same thing.

I added three fields to my master table: [TheYear], [TheLetter], [TheSequence]

[TheYear] Default value on the table is: = DatePart("yyyy",Date())
[TheLetter] Default value on the table is: = "SCR" --- or whatever you need the letter to be.
[TheSequence] is the # you assign to the record.

On the beforeinsert event on the form I used:

[TheSequence] = Nz(Dmax("[TheSequence]","TableName","[TheYear] = DatePart ("yyyy",Date) AND [TheLetter] = "SCR"), 0)+1

On the Click Event for the button on the form I did:

me.txtSCRID = [TheLetter]&"-"&[TheYear]&[TheSequence]

Code:
Private Sub Command67_Click()

Me.btnSave.Visible = True

Me.txtSCRID = [TheLetter] & "-" & [TheYear] & [TheSequence]

End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)

[TheSequence] = Nz(DMax("[TheSequence]", "Master Shared Compliance Review", [TheYear] = DatePart("yyyy", Date) And [TheLetter] = "SCR"), 0) + 1

End Sub

The end result is an ID Number "SCRID" of: SCR-20173 and so forth.

Please let me know if you see any shortcomings on this method. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to retain the existing `SCRnnnnn` format, you could probably do the following:

```
Public Function GetUID() As String

    GetUID = "SCR" & Format(CLng(Mid(DMax("[SCR ID]", "Master Shared Compliance Review"), 4)) + 1, "00000")

End Function
```

Comment: YowE3K, Thank you for your suggestion however it still doesn't move beyond the 1000 Number. I need to have it continually move up in numbers regardless of cap. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure why that wouldn't work.  If the current max was `"SCR00999"` then it would extract the `00999` part (using the `Mid(...,4)` bit of the code), convert it to a number (using the `CLng(...)` bit), add 1 (giving 1000), format that to be `01000` (using the `Format(...,"00000")` bit) and then concatenate that to `"SCR"` giving a value of `"SCR01000"`.

Answer (score 0):

use `Format(Number,"#0000") ' Format minimum 4 digit`

in your case

```
Format(nz(DMax("[SCR ID]", "Master Shared Compliance Review"),0),"#0000")

usage:
?format(1,"#0000")
0001
?format(100,"#0000")
0100
?format(1001,"#0000")
1001
?format(10001,"#0000")
10001
```

Comment: Krish KM, thank you for your response. I used the *Format(nz(DMax("[SCR ID]", "Master Shared Compliance Review"),0),"#0000")* as suggested but now it will not go above 999 and the "SCR" alpha is repeating three times example: SCRSCRSCR999  *Public Function GetUID() As String

    GetUID = "SCR" & Format(Nz(DMax("[SCR ID]", "Master Shared Compliance Review"), 0), "#000000000")

End Function

Comment: you should post your code that you've tried and probably your Dmax() result too

Comment: what does "GetUID = "SCR" & Format(1000, "#0000")" return??

Comment: Krish, it yields SCRSCR999       The code is:                                    Public Function GetUID() As String

    GetUID = "SCR" & Format(Nz(DMax("[SCR ID]", "Master Shared Compliance Review"), 0), "#000000000")

End Function

Comment: i think your [scr id] is a string field which already contains scrnnn number!!! you need to debug yourself.

Comment: Krish, thank you for your response. The SCR ID field is a text field. Forgive my ignorance but how would I go about debugging?